# How to compile mono projects from command line on mac

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I'm required to compile a C# project from the command line (not from within the IDE). It works just fine under linux (to be exact under Fedora and Ubuntu). I just install the mono-xbuild package and the build script is capable of executing the xbuild command. The problem is that there's no xbuild or mdtool inside the home-brew repositories and installing xamarin studio while building isn't the solution because it places the binary in different places depending on a whole range of conditions.
How do I get my build/install script to work out of the box under MacOSX?

Comment: I can't believe the `xbuild` binary is not there, can you double check? maybe it's under another name, `mono-xbuild` maybe?

Comment: Nope. There is no mono-xbuild or anything else named *xbuild* binary. It's really frustrating. There also isn't the mcs binary.

Comment: ok, and is there an `msbuild` binary?

Comment: No. msbuild is only available under windows (as far as I know) due to the fact that xbuild is an msbuild cone to reproduce its functionality under UNIX/mono.

Comment: you're not 100% correct there, msbuild has been recently open-sourced by Microsoft and so the Mono Project maintainers are in the process of adopting it and removing xbuild, so please look for an msbuild file in your Mono installation directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [.NET for macOS](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/macos), then use a `dotnet` command to run compile and execute a .NET project.

Here are the commands to run a Hello World's app:

```
dotnet new console -o myApp
cd myApp
dotnet run
```

For Mono apps, you need to install [Mono framework](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-mac) (available as a Mac `.pkg` file)

Consider also installing [MSBuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild) (The Microsoft Build Engine). It requires OpenSSL (install via: `brew install openssl`). See: [Building Testing and Debugging on .Net Core MSBuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/wiki/Building-Testing-and-Debugging-on-.Net-Core-MSBuild).